# Need help processing upload form with Google App Engine Blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm trying to learn the blobstore API... and I'm able to successfully upload files and get them back, but I'm not having any luck trying to combine an upload form with a regular webform to be able to associated extra info with the file, such as a nickname for the file.

Below is the code for a simple app I've been playing with. It's based on the sample google provides.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

import os
import urllib

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db

class StoredFiles(db.Model):
    nickname = db.StringProperty()
    blobkey = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()

    @staticmethod
    def get_all():
        query = db.Query(StoredFiles)
        files = query.get()

        return files


def doRender(handler, page, templatevalues=None):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), page)
    handler.response.out.write(template.render(path, templatevalues))

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        allfiles = StoredFiles.get_all()

        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')

        templatevalues = {
                'allfiles': allfiles,
                'upload_url': upload_url,

            }
        doRender(self, 'index.html', templatevalues)

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]

        self.redirect('/save/%s' % blob_info.key())

class SaveHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, resource):

        newFile = StoredFiles()
        newFile.nickname = self.request.get('nickname')
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        newFile.blobkey = resource

        newFile.put()

        self.redirect('/')

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
          [('/', MainHandler),
           ('/upload', UploadHandler),
           ('/save/([^/]+)?', SaveHandler),
          ], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

According to the docs, the blobstore handler is supposed to pass through the blob key and the rest of the form to the handler its redirected to... blob key is coming through just fine, but nothing else is.

Can someone please point out where I'm messing up or point me to a good tutorial describing this use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your posted form data is lost when you redirect the request to "/save/%s", which is normal.

Instead of redirecting, you should put your code inside UploadHandler, like this (untested code) :

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
            blob_info = upload_files[0]

            newFile = StoredFiles()
            newFile.nickname = self.request.get('nickname')
            newFile.blobkey = blob_info.key()
            newFile.put()

            self.redirect('/')
        except:
            self.redirect('/upload_failure.html')
```

See this page from the docs for a similar example : http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers.html#BlobstoreUploadHandler

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried something like this before and failed, but I'm sure there was some other error creeping in. Will try your solution later today.