# How do I call request handler in google appengine, python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I try to load file from form in two steps, and use BlobStoreUploadHandler.
At 1st step I recive form data with request handler, and check it for valid (the form action = "/a"). Then if form is valid, I want rewrite form action to upload_url, where

```
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/a')
```

and call the post request with new path_info. How do I call request with changed path_info?

```
class SendFormwithFile(webapp.RequestHandler):
    ...
    def post(self):
        ... 
        if form.is_valid():
            self.request.path_info = upload_url

        else:
            ...
            return form with error message
            ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new experimental code of [writing files](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to the blobstore which may suit your needs. Quote:

> App Engine allows you to programmatically create blobstore blobs, providing a file-like API that you can use to read and write to blobs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why you need to process this with a request handler first.

Here's the sample code I used that was originally posted as an answer to my question:

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
            blob_info = upload_files[0]

            newFile = StoredFiles()
            newFile.nickname = self.request.get('nickname')
            newFile.blobkey = blob_info.key()
            newFile.put()

            self.redirect('/')
        except:
            self.redirect('/upload_failure.html')
```

You can call form validation within the request handler for blobstore and move on to different paths depending on whether validation passed or not.

Here's the link to the question/answer with more details: [Need help processing upload form with Google App Engine Blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887535/need-help-processing-upload-form-with-google-app-engine-blobstore)